# Regular Expression : begin with specific words and exclude group of words

Tags: regex

I have some text in different patterns like below:

```
bg_table1
bg_table2
bg_table3

mp_table1
mp_table2
mp_table3

user_profile 
action_history
artifact_group
```

It would be great if someone could provide me "regular expression" sample to select:

1. Text starts with either **bg_**  or **mp_** only

   ```
   mp_table1
   mp_table2
   mp_table3
   ```
2. Text does not start with **bg_** or **mp_** or **any other pattern** I will provide

   ```
   user_profile
   action_history
   artifact_group
   ```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: *Text does not start with bg_ or mp_ or **any other pattern*** - what does that mean, any other pattern? This condition sounds irrelevant.

Comment: Let's say ,  text start with bg_, mp_ or in future it could by another one like cp_. For the time being just forget about "any other pattern". Just consider "Text does not start with bg_ or mp_" - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for matching bg/mp/others

```
\b(?:bg|mp)_\S+
```

https://regex101.com/r/HIo1nl/1/

Use this for not matching bg/mp/others:

```
\S+(?<!\b(?:bg|mp))_\S+
```

https://regex101.com/r/Sgj9HE/2/

I've used `\S+` for the words, which mean "anything but spaces" You may replace those by `\w+` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` or any other thing if you want to be more restrictive.

`\w+` allows letters, numbers and `_`

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+` would just allow letters and numbers.

Comment: @Toto Thanks, fixed! \W was a typo, "-" my bad memory :)

Comment: much better now ;)